# Wildcard within wildcard in Snakemake

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have very recently started using Snakemake.

What I am trying to achieve is this: I have some `samples` which need to be modified, independently (rule `index_vcf`). Then, groups of samples are the input of another rule (`analyse`), and we get an output for each group in `groups`.

I would like the second rule to run two commands:

```
some_script --input_files 'A2 Ah AL' --output ../out/A.out
```

and

```
some_script --input_files 'Banana BLM' --output ../out/B.out
```

I know how to do it if it's just for one group, but if I do it for both, then the wildcard `sample_from_group` which I am expanding in `analyse` needs to depend on the group and I get the error

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is my config file:

```
groups:
-   A
-   B

samples:
- A2
- Ah
- AL
- Banana
- BLM

grouped_samples:
  A: A2_mod, Ah_mod, AL_mod
  B: Banana_mod, BLM_mod
```

and this is my Snakefile

```
configfile: "config_PCAWG.yaml"
samples = config["samples"]
groups = config["groups"]
grouped_samples = config["grouped_samples"]


rule all:
    input:
      expand("../out/{group}.out", group = groups)

rule index_vcf:
    input:
        "../data/{sample}"
    output:
        "../data/{sample}_mod"
    shell:
        "tabix -f {input}"

rule analyse:
    input:
        expand("{sample_from_group}", sample_from_group=grouped_samples[{group}].split())
    output:
         "../out/{group}.out
    shell:
        "some_script --input_files '{input}' --output {output}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to correct misprints (e.g. there is a string that has no closeing quote). Next, there is a logical error in that no rule produces anything that matches the pattern `"../out/{group}.out"`. Did you mean `"../data/{group}.out"`?

Now the main part. This is an invalid syntax:

```
        expand("{sample_from_group}", sample_from_group=grouped_samples[{group}].split())
```

What you meant is a lambda (or a function) that takes a wildcard and produces an expand:

```
rule analyse:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand("{sample_from_group}",
                             sample_from_group=grouped_samples[wildcards.group].split())
```

Comment: thank you! I have ammended the typo `../data` -> `../out `  for the output folders